# What kind of informations show when validation of AntiForgeryToken fails?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, antiforgerytoken

I have public site with some forms.

Simple question:
What kind of informations should I show when validation of AntiForgeryToken fails?

Is it should be 404 (page not found), error or just ignore it and redirect to the home page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return an appropriate status code. 404 means that the requested resource is not found which is not the case with anti forgery token validation failure.

`403 Forbidden` seems like a reasonable status code to return in this case. It means that the server understood the request but refused to fulfill it.

Comment: You suggest to create special page (403) with additional informations about this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be 400 Bad Request